Mongodb connection failed nodejs application
i am trying to bulid a e commerce applicaton so as to build an admin page i tried to store data in mongodb so i tried to connect the mongodb in localhost as i am beginner please help me with this
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const state={
  db:null
}

module.exports.connect=function(done){
  const url='mongodb://localhost:27017'
  const dbname='shopping'

  mongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
    if(err) return done(err)
      state.db=data.db(dbname)
    done()
  })


}

module.exports.get=function(){
  return state.db
}

I want to just connect my application to mongodb
